# Solve: $(i+i^2+i^3+...+i^{102})^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve $$(i+i^2+i^3+...+i^{102})^2$$

I have tried 2 approaches:

1. to look at power of $2 (=-1)$ and power of $4 (=1)$ and there are $102$ elements which is even number, but because there are $4$ "types" $\{i,-1,-i,1\}$ it did not work it out
2. to look at 
   $$(i+i^2+i^3+...+i^{102})^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{102}i^k\right)^2$$ but $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{102}i^k\right)^2\neq \sum_{k=1}^{102}i^{2k}$$ so it was not useful.

Any suggestion how to tackle this?

Comment: WolfRamAlpha says -2i

Comment: Are you familiar with the sum of a geometric progession $\sum_{k=1}^{N} r^k = \frac{r-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINTS:

$$i+i^2+i^3+i^4=0,$$

$$i^{4m+n}=i^{n}.$$

Comment: It may be useful for the OP to note of course a slight generalisation; that if $\omega$ is an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$; so $\omega^n -1 =0$, then $\omega^n-1= (\omega -1)(\omega^{n-1} + \dots + \omega + 1)$. So if $\omega \ne 1$ then we get that $\omega^{n-1} + \dots + \omega + 1=0$

Answer (score 4):

One trick for this kind of problem is to work it out for small numbers and see if you can find a pattern. Try working out:
$$ i + i^2 $$
$$ i + i^2 + i^3 $$
$$ i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 $$
$$ i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 + i^5 $$
$$ i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 + i^5 + i^6$$
Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Should the $i^3$'s on the left toward the bottom be squared instead?

Comment: @Chickenmancer Hah, yes, thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$a + a^2 + a^3 + \dots a^n = a\frac{1-a^{n}}{1-a}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
(i+i^2 + \cdots + i^{102}) &= i \frac{1-i^{102}}{1-i}\\
& = i \frac{1-i^{100}i^2}{1-i} \\
 &= i \frac{1+(i^{4})^{25}}{1-i}\\
 &= \frac{2i}{1-i}\\
&= -1 + i
\end{align*}

Squaring yields $-2i$.

Comment: I don't think geometric summing is useful here. The trick is that most of the sum cancels to zero.

Comment: Why isn't it useful?

Comment: It isn't that useful because to figure out what $i^{103}$ is you should see that the sum is $25S+i-1$ where $S=i+i^2+i^3+i^4$.

Comment: Because in this case, the seeing that the terms are periodic allows a more elegant solution. (Not saying you're *wrong*, just saying that this solution obscures the fact that the summands cancel)

Comment: Just giving an alternative method. No need to downvote.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more with you "geometric progression haters."  You can see the cancellation which took place in the rear view mirror after you have quickly found the answer using the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: The method is correct and gives a good answer. Furthermore it relates a common technique into the problem. Worth an upvote imo

Comment: @sharding4 How do I find $i^{103}$ and how does that show me that the sum of four consecutive powers of $i$ is zero? I don't hate GP --- it is very useful --- but in this case I prefer other approaches.

Comment: $i^{103}$ is kind of an intermediate algebra problem.  I think students are normally taught that the powers of $i$ are cyclic when imaginary numbers are introduced, so $i^{103}=i^{100}\cdot i^3= -i$  I do believe there is a problem with Math_QED's indices though, isn't there?

Comment: @sharding4 "You can see the cancellation which took place in the rear view mirror" This is the bit I don't understand.

Comment: The idea is if I sum any sequence of ocmplex numbers, but in particular root sof unity, say $\sum _{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_N^k=0$ where $\zeta_N$ is a primitive $N^{th}$ root of unity, I know there was cancellation.  I just added up $N$ terms and got $0$.

Comment: @sharding4 Yes maybe if the answer separated $\sum_{n\leq 100}i^n$ and $i^{101}+i^{102}$.

Comment: Again please fix the indices on your sum of the geometric progression.  You're off by 1.  Should be $a\frac{1-a^{n}}{1-a}$, no?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy  Your answer does cut the problem down to nothing quite nicely.  Hard to argue with that.

Comment: @Math_QED I didn't downvote. Aesthetic/tactical disagreement $\neq$ belief you're incorrect :)

Comment: @Math_QED I did downvote. I upvoted Neal's.

Comment: I really don't get why people are still downvoting this answer without justification.

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea works:

If $n=4k+1$ then $i^n = i$,

If $n=4k+2$ then $i^n = -1$,

If $n=4k+3$ then $i^n = -i$,

If $n=4k$ then $i^n = 1$

So,
$i+i^2+i^3+i^4=0$
$i^5+i^6+i^7+i^8=0$

.

.

.

$i^{97}+i^{98}+i^{99}+i^{100}=0$

Then, in the sum $i+i^2+i^3+...+i^{102}$ the only left terms are $i^{101}+i^{102}=i-1$

Thus, $(i+i^2+i^3+...+i^{102})^2=(i-1)^2= i^2 -2i+1=-1-2i+1=-2i$

Answer (score 0):

$$i=i\\i^2 =-1\\i^3 =-i \\i^4 =1$$
Thus, $$\sum_{k=1}^{4n} i^k =0\  \text{for positive integer}\  n$$,
Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^{102} i^k=\sum_{k=1}^{2} i^k=-1+i$$
And it's square equals $-2i$